# Does the family of binomial distributions conditioned on $X > 0$ belong to the exponential family?

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution, exponential-family

> Does the family of distributions where $p(x,\theta)$ is the conditional frequency function of a binomial $\mathcal{B}(n,\theta)$, variable $X$, given that $X > 0$, belong to the exponential family?

**My Attempt**

As it is known, the binomial distribution is given by
\begin{align*}
p(x,\theta) = {{n}\choose{x}}\theta^{x}(1-\theta)^{n-x}
\end{align*}

Thus we get the following expression for the conditional distribution
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(X = x|X > 0) & = \frac{\textbf{P}(X = x,X > 0)}{\textbf{P}(X > 0)}\\
& = \frac{\displaystyle{{n}\choose{x}}\theta^{x}(1-\theta)^{n-x}}{1 - \textbf{P}(X = 0)}\\
& = \frac{\displaystyle{{n}\choose{x}}\theta^{x}(1-\theta)^{n-x}}{1-(1 - \theta)^{n}}
\end{align*}

This is as far as I can get. Can someone help me solve this exercise?

Comment: Can you show that ordinary binomial distributions belong to the exponential family?  If so, what stops you using the same argument here?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Binomial_distribution.